# Spring JAX-RS client - get response status

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I have injected a JAX-RS client via a spring context
like this :

```
<jaxrs:client id="restClient"
       address="http://localhost:${testutil.ports.BookServerRestSoap}/test/services/rest"
       serviceClass="org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.BookStoreJaxrsJaxws">
</jaxrs:client>
```

How can I access the response status in the case of a success response (200, 202, 204) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as follows,

```
org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.BookStoreJaxrsJaxws proxy = ctx.getBean(org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.BookStoreJaxrsJaxws.class);

Response response = proxy.method();
```

Comment: for the json provider we have to use that one `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps defined in this post https://java2blog.com/restful-web-services-jaxrs-crud-example/#comment-11493 . I did not change any file in my local yet. But finally, http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/rest/countries saying 404 issue. http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/ is showing “Hello World” in the browser.